# Can i stop or start the html marquee when hovering on the images which are arranged in that marquee?

Tags: html, css

Can i stop or start the html marquee when hovering on the images which are arranged in that marquee?

here marquee stops when hovering full marquee div. but i want this to stop when hover on the images which are in this marquee?

Answer (score 1):

Yes You can start or stop marquee on mouse over and out here is html code

```
     <marquee direction="left" onmouseover="this.stop()" onmouseout="this.start()" scrollamount="3">
     <img src="imageurl.jpg />
     <img src="imageurl.jpg />
     <img src="imageurl.jpg />
     <img src="imageurl.jpg />
     <img src="imageurl.jpg />
    </marquee>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/C4Y2B/) what you are looking for??

```
    <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" onmousedown="this.stop();" onmouseup="this.start();">Go on... click me (and hold the mouse down)!</marquee>
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would use this.Stop() and this.Start() on mouseover and mouseout. You can also do this on the child elements and use this.parentNode.Stop() and this.parentNode.Start(). Then the marquee will stop if you only hover the child elements.

In the example of the other answer this would be the image tag:

```
<img src="imageurl.jpg" onmouseover="this.parentNode.stop()" onmouseout="this.parentNode.start()" />
```

You can remove the mouseover and mouseout from the marquee tag, you don't need them any more.